# Remove specified OCSP responder from certificate

Tags: ssl-certificate, ocsp

OCSP is brain-damaged and a privacy violation. Is there a way I can remove the specified OCSP responder from a certificate file to prevent my site's visitors from having to suffer it?

From what I understand, OCSP stapling would be great if it had browser support, though unfortunately I cannot use it at all in my current server configuration. :(

Comment: OCSP can be great for enterprises running their own PKI infrastructure.  But yes, it seems a bit silly for public certs from third party CAs.

Comment: first: most (if not all) browsers don't request OCSP if the site does not have an Extended Validation certificate. Second: if you want to protect user's privacy, use ocsp stapling. Third: request for ocsp is harder to eavesdrop than the http request so for stuff like www OCSP privacy problems are rather overblown

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't believe so.  Modifying the X.509 attributes in the public certificate would change the certificate's thumbprint hash, and invalidate the signature from the CA that issued the certificate.

Comment: I sort of suspected this but wanted a second opinion. Oh well. Thanks anyway.